# anyone care to look at this and comment?

Tags: discussion

[Alias-free digital nonlinear filter design](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51533/alias-free-digital-nonlinear-filter-design/51556?noredirect=1#comment102723_51556)

i am really trying to hold my tongue.  in fact, i am openly declaring that i don't grok the answer and would simply like it explained in language we all understand.

Comment: You should probably flag your own post requesting for comment thread clean-up/moving to chat. The long winding personal conflict comments shouldn't be there in the first place. That's **not** what the comments are for.